# Could we arrange things so that simply editing the tags doesn't bump a question up to the top of the "active" list?

Tags: feature-request

Could we arrange things so that simply editing the tags doesn't bump a question up to the top of the "active" list?  Or is that baked into the architecture of Stack Exchange?

(I thought I had noticed that editing tags did *not* bump a question up to the top of the "active" list, but now I see that obviously I was wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not something we can control.

This has been suggested before, so I suggest you go and register your agreement with the suggestion: [It should be possible to retag a question without bumping it to the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/it-should-be-possible-to-retag-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page)

Comment: OK, done, thanks.